# What is the meaning of this regular expression in java script

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the meaning of this expression. Unable to understand ?

```
function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
```

Comment: [*what have you tried?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Go do some [research](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? It's a simple [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), and every occurence is replaced by itself preceded by a backslash.

Comment: Why do you use(or want to use) it when you don't understand what it does?

Comment: I am reading a tutorial and trying to understand what is going on .. so I am not using it anywhere right now

Comment: Everyone I have just started learning the javascript and I know what replace function do I just not able to understand the meaning of regular expression so please do not down vote because I am learning phase

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript

Comment: @zzzzBov I am learning it from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Statements and was unable to interpret it

Comment: @Ashish, "please do not down vote because I am learning phase" no, that's not how it works. As per the downvote text: "This question does not show any research effort". If you were to show in some way that you had used a resource to learn regular expressions, then I'd consider helping explain the details of the parts where you're having issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has the function of introducing a backslash character `\` before certain characters in that regular expression set `[...]`.

The characters are: `. * + ? ^ = ! : $ { } ( ) | [ ] / \`

Note that some of these are necessarily escaped with `\` because they have special meaning within the context of a regular expression, like `/`, and within a set, like `]`.

The outer brackets in the regular expression have the effect of "capturing" the resulting match, and in the second argument to the function, `$1` is the result of that capture. The `/g` option means to repeat "globally", or as many times as it will match.

Comment: `/` actually does not have any special meaning in a regulare expression - it's just a slash. It's only relevant in a regex literal which is delimited by slashes.

Comment: @Bergi It has a particular meaning in *this* regular expression is a more correct phrasing. You're right in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

This function will insert a backslash just before the following characters in `string`, and return the result:

```
 . * + ? ^ = ! : $ { } ( ) | [ ] / \
```